# Not able to use CompositetextinputFormat in Mapside Join

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, high-availability

I am trying to implement Map-side join using `CompositeTextInoutFormat`. However I am getting below errors in Map reduce job which I am unable to resolve,.
1. In the below code I am getting error while using Compose method and also getting an error while setting inputformat Class. The error says as below.

> The method compose(String, Class, Path...) in
>   the type CompositeInputFormat is not applicable for the   arguments
>   (String, Class, Path[])

Can someone please help

```
package Hadoop.MR.Practice;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.join.CompositeInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.join.CompositeInputFormat;


public class MapJoinJob implements Tool{

private Configuration conf;     

public Configuration getConf() {
    return conf;
}
public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
    this.conf = conf;
}
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "MapSideJoinJob");
    job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());

    Path[] inputs = new Path[] { new Path(args[0]), new Path(args[1])};
    String join = CompositeInputFormat.compose("inner", KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, inputs);
    job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.join.expr", join);

    job.setInputFormatClass(CompositeInputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MapJoinMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    //Configuring reducer
    job.setReducerClass(WCReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    MapJoinJob mjJob = new MapJoinJob();
    ToolRunner.run(conf, mjJob, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say your problem is likely related to mixing hadoop APIs. You can see that your imports are mixing `mapred` and `mapreduce`.

For example, you're trying to use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat` with `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.join.CompositeInputFormat` which is unlikely to work.

You should choose one (probably `mapreduce` i would say) and make sure everything is using the same API.